# Why Sahi Automated Test Cases aren't running in IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, bdd, testcase, sahi, behat

I am new to Sahi Testing tool.
I recorded some test cases using Sahi, when I play back in IE 8..

On my Terminal I am getting error:
**Window/Domain not found:  popupNameFromStep=; derivedName=; windowName=; windowTitle=XD Proxy; wasOpened=0;**

And IE also shows an warning popup which says :
**"To help protect you security, Internet explorer has blocked this site from displaying content with security certificate errors."**
When I click it and choose "Dispaly Blocked Content" , it does nothing and shows same above warning pop-up.
I don't understand how these test cases are running fine in other browsers?

Please help..Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pure Sahi error. Send them your error: http://sahi.co.in/w/sahi-community

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this issue.
**Issue was** - Automated Tests using Sahi Tool were not running in IE8.

**Reason for this** -

1. IE8 checks for the XPath whenever we run tests via sahi. Actually,
   XPaths are natively enabled on Firefox. For browsers like Internet
   Explorer which do not have support for XPath use Javascript-XPath.
2. There was problem with certificates blocking by IE due to security reasons.

**How to fix** -

1. Copy the contents of javascript-xpath-latest.js and save the
   contents to
   sahi/htdocs/spr/ext/javascript-xpath/javascript-xpath.js.
2. For fixing certicate issue i have seen this video :
   [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qfjjVUGW56s)
   It tells about how we can manually add certificates in IE.

---

For any query related to Sahi you can go to Sahi Forums :
http://sahi.co.in/forums/